# Deadlock in Go, two routines splitting work

Tags: go, deadlock, goroutine, channel

I'm a bit stuck on a deadlock issue in go.

This program takes an array of ints, a, and splits it into two. Then it takes these two parts in two different routines and sum up all elements. After this, it's supposed to send the two results in the channel res. The two res (now ch) then should be added together and print.

My problem: I've tried to tackle the deadlock problem by moving about close-functions a lot, but nothing seems to help. It works well with only one routine Add running obviously.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

// Add adds the numbers in a and sends the result on res.
func Add(a []int, res chan<- int) {
    sum := 0
    for i := range a {
        sum = sum + a[i]
    }
    res <- sum
}

func main() {
    a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}

    n := len(a)
    ch := make(chan int)
    go Add(a[:n/2], ch)
    go Add(a[n/2:], ch)


    sum := 0
    for s := range ch {
        sum = sum + s
    }
    //close(ch)

    fmt.Println(sum)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're never closing the channel so there's no signal for the `range` to quit. It'll just keep on trying to receive, but there's nothing left that's sending.

You would either need to have some way for your `Add()` function to see when it ends if it is the last one so that it can `close()` the channel, or you could just decrement a counter instead of using `range` in the loop so that you don't need to use `close()`.

```
func main() {
    a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}

    n := len(a)
    ch := make(chan int)
    go Add(a[:n/2], ch)
    go Add(a[n/2:], ch)

    sum := 0

    // counts the number of messages sent on the channel
    count := 0

    // run the loop while the count is less than the total number of routines
    for count < 2 {
        s := <-ch
        sum = sum + s
        count++  // Increment the count after a routine sends its value
    }
    fmt.Println(sum)
}
```

***DEMO:*** http://play.golang.org/p/oHcrUStjmm

Comment: Thanks! So simple! I was so focused on only using the range, it blinded me.

Comment: You can simplify even more in this case: from the initialisation of sum onwards, you just need one line: `sum := <-ch + <-ch`. See http://play.golang.org/p/sVt_82KPuP